# função maskMoney do jquery não funciona em div carregada via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho uma página em que estou dando refresh com `ajax` apenas na `div conteúdo`. Ela está configurada assim:

div1: Carrego 2 selects onde o usuário escolherá estes 2 dados (classe e bimestre)

div 2: Carrego o menu da aplicação (menu.php) fim da div 2

div id="conteudo": Carrego a página que lê os 2 selects e carrega a página php correspondente, de acordo com o item escolhido no menu na `div2` fim da `div id="conteudo"`

Na página principal, onde tenho todas estas divs, uso a função `maskMoney` do jquery para mascarar meus inputs somente como números decimais.
Quando coloco um input dentro das divs superiores (1 e 2) o maskMoney funciona perfeitamente.
Quando um input é carregado pelo ajax dentro da div conteudo, o `maskMoney` não funciona.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender porque isso ocorre e como resolver?

Comment: coloque seu código para que os usuários do fórum possam te ajudar da melhor forma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, Regina
Aparentemente só está funcionando nas div's que não usam ajax porque você deve ter utilizado o comando de estilização do jquery Mask no momento em que sua página carrega. Sendo necessário agora reexecutar a função do plugin

Tente adicionar o código que aplica a máscara no componente de novo no momento em que recebe o retorno da consulta ajax, isso deve resolver seu problema.

Editado:

Código:

```js
function AlteraConteudo() {
    var ajax = AjaxF();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById('conteudo').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            //Aqui você executa os comandos do plugin novamente
        }
    };
    dados = "classe=" + document.getElementById('classes').value + "&bimestre=" + document.getElementById('bimestre').value + "&ano=" + document.getElementById('ano').value + "&tipo=" +document.getElementById('tipo').value;
    var pagina = document.getElementById('pagina').value;
    ajax.open("GET", pagina + dados, false);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    ajax.send();
}
```

Att

Bruno Miquelotto

Comment: Entendi a lógica Bruno. faz todo sentido e deve ser isso mesmo. A função da máscara é rodada no $(document).ready(function(){, que acho que siginifica o completo carregamento da página, não é?
Agora vem a dúvida, já que não entendo nada de ajax, como fazer o que vc falou de adicionar o código no carregamento da consulta ajax?

Comment: Poste o seu código ajax aqui pra gente ver

Comment: // Função que verifica se o navegador tem suporte AJAX 
function AjaxF()
{
 var ajax;
 
 try
 {
  ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } 
 catch(e) 
 {
  try
  {
   ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
  catch(e) 
  {
   try 
   {
    ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   catch(e) 
   {
    alert("Seu browser não da suporte à AJAX!");
    return false;
   }
  }
 }
 return ajax;
}

//

Comment: Me desculpe, mas não sei mexer direito aqui. O código ficou muito ruim de olhar? Não achei como anexar um arquivo aqui no post

Comment: O trecho de código é apenas esse ? Porque esse código não faz a requisição, apenas verifica se o navegado suporta ajax

Comment: function AlteraConteudo()
{
 var ajax = AjaxF(); 
 ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(ajax.readyState == 4)
  {
   document.getElementById('conteudo').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
  }
 }
 var dados = "classe="+document.getElementById('classes').value+"&bimestre="+document.getElementById('bimestre').value+"&ano="+document.getElementById('ano').value+"&tipo="+document.getElementById('tipo').value;
 var pagina = document.getElementById('pagina').value;
 ajax.open("GET", pagina + dados, false);
 ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
 ajax.send();
}

Comment: faltou esta parte do código...

Comment: vou tentar fazer e qq coisa volto aqui. obrigada

Comment: Muito obrigada. deu certíssimo. abraços